# DiscretizeRegion fails on a simple implicit region

Tags: regions, mesh, discretization

No matter what option I set to `DiscretizeRegion` it fails on the region (missing second line).

What else can be done?

```
$Version
Region[ImplicitRegion[(1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) <= x <= 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]) ||
      x >= 1) && y == 5/100, {x, y}], PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}},
  Axes -> True]

DiscretizeRegion[%, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}, Axes -> True, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 10, MaxCellMeasure -> 1/10, 
 MeshQualityGoal -> "Maximal"]
```

---

```
"13.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)"
```

[image]

For a similar region it works:

```
Region[ImplicitRegion[(1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) <= x <= -1 || 
     x >= 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5])) && y == 1/20, {x, y}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}, Axes -> True]

DiscretizeRegion[%, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}, Axes -> True, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 10, MaxCellMeasure -> 1/10, 
 MeshQualityGoal -> "Maximal"]
```

---

[image]

Comment: Could it be because the region is not bounded?

Comment: On other unbounded regions it works. For example `ImplicitRegion[(1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) <= x <= -1 || 
    x >= 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5])) && y == 1/20, {x, y}]`

Answer (score 4):

- add data range  `{{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}` before `PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}`

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[(1/2  (-1 - Sqrt[5]) <= x <= 
       1/2  (-1 + Sqrt[5]) || x >= 1) && y == 5/100, {x, y}];
DiscretizeRegion[reg, {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

- Another way is only use `RegionPlot`.

```
RegionPlot[reg, Method -> {"DiscretizationMethod" -> "Symbolic"}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> False, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: I need the plot range as is specified.

Comment: @azerbajdzan   as my updated answer or  use `Show[..., PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}]`

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround by adding `LogicalExpand` in the code.

```
Region[ImplicitRegion[
  LogicalExpand[(1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) <= x <= 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]) || 
      x >= 1) && y == 5/100], {x, y}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}, Axes -> True]

DiscretizeRegion[%, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}, Axes -> True, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 10, MaxCellMeasure -> 1/10, 
 MeshQualityGoal -> "Maximal"]
```

---

[image]